# Auto-resizing UITableViewCell shadow is off

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` with a self sizing `UILabel` and a shadow.

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var cellBackgroundView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var creationDateLabel: UILabel!

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.cellBackgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 12

    self.cellBackgroundView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(1.0).cgColor
    self.cellBackgroundView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    self.cellBackgroundView.layer.shadowRadius = 9
    self.cellBackgroundView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
    self.cellBackgroundView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.cellBackgroundView.bounds).cgPath
    self.cellBackgroundView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.cellBackgroundView.layer.shouldRasterize = true

    self.cellBackgroundView.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
  }
}
```

I've tried to implement this code in `layoutSubviews()`, `cellForRowAt: indexPath` and `willDisplay cell` but it is always off and not centered:

[image: Shadow is not centered but off]
What's the correct way to implement it?

**Edit:** It works when I start scrolling in the tableView.

**Edit 2:** This is how it should look like:

[image: This is how it should look!]

Thanks!

Comment: What is "always off and not centered" ?

Comment: @Koen You can see it in the image I've attached. The shadow should be directly under the cell. I'll post a photo of how it should look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the code you posted *without* the line:

```
self.cellBackgroundView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.cellBackgroundView.bounds).cgPath
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: This is sweet! Works!